# How can I reset table.DefaultView.RowFilter?

Tags: c#, datatable, reset, rowfilter, defaultview

The code below works fine and filters the rows correctly but how would I restore the table to its original state?

```
DataTable table = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = comboBox.Text + " LIKE '%" + strName + "%'";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try this:

```
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty
```

Answer (score 3):

This works also like a charm:

```
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = null /Nothing
```