# Search engine of my form does not return complete records when empty

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem with the search engine of my form it does not return the complete records when it is empty it stays stuck with the last search instead of returning all the records.

This is my code

```
Private Sub txtBuscar_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBuscar.TextChanged
Try
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim dtv As DataView
If txtBuscar.Text.Trim =
dtv = tb.Defaultview
dtv.RowFilter = "Material like'%" & txtBuscar.Text &"%'"
grdMateria.DataSource = dtv
grdMateria.Refresh()
Then Exit Sub 
Then
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End sub
```

Comment: I suggest that the code needs to check for if `txtBuscar.Text = ""`, then see [How can I reset table.DefaultView.RowFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1009932/1115360)

Comment: Is that code even syntactically correct ? And there is something wrong here: you silently swallow exceptions. Which means that errors may be occurring but you silence them.